# Unit Test not running Angular4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run unit test in Angular 4 using Chrome, There are some error thrown in the chrome console, no idea how to fix this issue, have looked at Google not much help found.
this is the error I am getting, If anybody have a solution will be highly appreciated.
thanks in advance.

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js:33
    at Object.<anonymous> (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js:34)
    at Object../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js (devmode.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 60e3023d24bd9e093b52:54)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:32)
    at Object../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js (http.js:567)
    at __webpack_require__ (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 60e3023d24bd9e093b52:54)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:29)
    at Object../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js (index.js:255)
    at __webpack_require__ (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 60e3023d24bd9e093b52:54)
```

Comment: Pretty simple actually. `fs.existsSync` is a Node.js runtime function that is most definitely not supported in Browsers. Browsers cannot even shim it since they cannot access the file system.

Comment: I am testing  normal web application , it is not accessing any files specifically.

Comment: So it fails like that even you don't run any user code? Make sure everything is up to date including your installation of Node.js

Comment: I have latest Node and Angular

Comment: It may run if you downgrade your node version to 6.*.*

Comment: remove "selenium-webdriver" from the karma configuration, when this is not the problem remove it from package.json when not needed, delete node_modules, then run npm install to install the stuff again. Install for e2e the chromedriver manually, so webpack doesn't try to build something wrong.